# Converting input numerical string in C

Tags: c, algorithm

The question is to write a program that takes an integer keyed in from the terminal and extracts and displays each digit of the integer in English. so, if a user types 932, the program should display 'nine three two'..

My algorithm is to reverse the number first so that 932 becomes 239. Now I extract the last digit using mod operator and print. Next I divide the number by 10, then I extract the last digit again and so on...

Is there any other algorithm (shorter and efficient) possible?

It is possible to extract the last digit of an integer. Is it possible to extract the first digit and so on?

Comment: Why not get user input using `fgets/fgetc`? No need of reversing, mod etc. Just read out!

Comment: How would your algorithm handle 120?

Comment: Why not just read the number as a string and skip the whole mod thing?

Comment: Extracting the last digit of an unsigned int for base 10 would just be `n % 10'. Voila!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip all mod processing/reversing if you input the string with `fgets` etc

Something on these lines ( No error checking on my part, its just a pseudo code )

```
char *numArray[]={"One", "Two", ....};

fgets(buffer, 80, stdin)

while ( buffer[i] )
{
    printf("%s ", numArray[buffer[i]-'0'])
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I would make an array `arrNums[10]={"Zero", "One", ... , "Nine"};`, and then just `printf("%s ", arrNums[buffer[i]-'0']);`

Comment: @Yuri Thanks Yuri, I incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: In you suggestion you have an array of chars, you will need an array of strings, so `char *numArray[]`

Answer (score 0):

You should really just process the string as suggested by the comments and Pavan, but given an integer in base ten you can extract the `nth` digit by:

```
floor( (a % (10**n)) / (10**(n-1)) )
```

Where `**` is exponention (`pow` in C `<math.h>`). If you happen to be working in a different base `b`, this still works:

```
floor( (a % (b**n)) / (b**(n-1)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading the posts I would have written it as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char bar(char foo) {
    char *bar[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    return foo <= '9' && foo >= '0'? printf("%s", bar[foo - '0']) : 0;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char buf[128];
    int len;

    printf("Give input: ");
    fgets(buf, 128, stdin);

    for(len = 0; buf[len]; len++) {
        if(bar(buf[len]))
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int n){
    static char *digit_name[] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine" };
    int q = n / 10;
    int r = n % 10;
    if(q != 0){
        print(q);
        putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("%s",digit_name[r]);
}

int main(void){
    print(932);
    return 0;
}
```